# Spring Security: How to get endpoint's authorities in Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In spring boot project I have a controller which has an endpoint with `@PreAuthorize` annotation

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
class SomeController {
  
    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SOME_AUTHORITY')")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> doSomething() {

    }
}
```

And also I have a filter that extends the `OncePerRequestFilter`

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain f) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //here I want to get the authorities specified in the controllers' endpoints
    }
}
```

The question is how to get controllers' endpoints' authorities specified by the `@PreAuthorize` annotation in the above filter?

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve the authorities in the filter? Why don't use the `authorizeHttpRequests()` DSL?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio in the filter there is a logic where I must filter some attributes based on authorities and set in Authentication object.

Comment: @BenoArakelyan care to add some more details? This sounds like a complete antipattern.

Comment: @ThomasRS I know. It is for solving business logic I don't want to write business details.

Comment: Filters shouldn't be used for business logic. Filter is for security or auditing. What attributes would you want to remove? If they are security related then you are doing security wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to move `hasAuthority('SOME_AUTHORITY')` into separate method in spring bean and use that method in filter and in `@PreAuthorize` annotation. In that way you will have common place for validate logic and you will keep code consistency as well.

Let me know if you need code examples.

Comment: How will the method give authorities in a filter and how can method be used in the `@PreAuthorize` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Spring Security's way, by using Pointcuts similar to `AuthorizationMethodPointcuts`. `AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor` reads these annotations using this pointcut.

GitHub link to spring-security for reference.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authorization

Comment: if you have trouble making it work, let me know. I can write the complete code for your Filter and post

Answer (score 0):

A filter dynamically intercepts requests and responses to transform or use the information contained in the requests or responses. Filters typically do not themselves create responses, but instead provide universal functions that can be "attached" to any endpoint.

**OncePerRequestFilter** . Spring guarantees that the OncePerRequestFilter is executed only once for a given request.

In your case you are extending OncePerRequestFilter in AuthTokenFilter and as you mentioned in comment you are authorizing user in this filter if user have valid details (in this case setting Authentication object).

- Once you will hit your endpoint Spring will execute AuthTokenFilter logic
- If details will valid then AuthTokenFilter will set Authentication in Spring context.
- Spring Security supports authorization at the method level with help of different type of annotation like @PreAuthorize, @Secured . But  enable annotation based security, we need to add the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation on any @Configuration class. example :

  ```
   @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
      prePostEnabled = true, 
      securedEnabled = true, 
      jsr250Enabled = true)
    public class MethodSecurityConfiguration {
        //default configuration class
    }
  ```
- HttpSecurity is tied to URL endpoints while @PreAuthorize is tied to controller methods and is actually located within the code adjacent to the controller definitions.
- authorities/roles should set in Authentication object inside AuthTokenFilter (in your case)  and those role can validated with  @PreAuthorize annotation.
- @PreAuthorize will trigger after AuthTokenFilter  filter